# Wall Script Return Comments (FuelPHP)

Tags: jquery, ajax, fuelphp

I ran into a problem that I can't solve.

I created a wall similar to Facebook's and it all works fine. What I've never done is returned comments this way; I'm clueless with how to return comments to the stream posts.

Here is my code

The Model

```
class Main extends \Model {

    static function post_stream()
    {
        DB::set_charset('utf8');
        $query = DB::insert('stream_post');

        $query->set(array(
            'stream_text' => \Input::post('stream_post'),
            'user_id' => \Session::get('sentry_user'),
            //'date' => time(),
        ));

        $query->execute();
    }

    static function get_stream()
    {
        $query = DB::select()->from('stream_post');
        $query->join('users_metadata');
        $query->on('stream_post.user_id', '=', 'users_metadata.user_id');
        $query->order_by('stream_post.stream_id', 'DESC');
        $result = $query->execute();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    static function post_stream_comment()
    {
        $query = DB::insert('stream_comment');

        $query->set(array(
            'user_id' => \Session::get('sentry_user'),
            'stream_id' => \Input::post('comment_post'),
            'comment_text' => \Input::post('comment_text'),
            )
        );

        $query->execute();
    }
```

View (I load this with jQuery load)

```
<div class="stream-posts">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
        <div id="post_<?php echo $post['stream_id']; ?>" class="span6 stream-content">
            <span class="user"><a href="#"><?php echo $post['full_name']; ?></a></span>
            <p><?php echo Input::auto_link(Input::nl2br_limit($post['stream_text'], 2)); ?></p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="feedback">
                <a href="#" class="like" rel="nofollow">Tetszik</a> - 
                <a href="#" class="comment" rel="nofollow">Hozzászólás</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="stream-comment">
                <form class="stream-comment-form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post" value="<?php echo $post['stream_id']; ?>">
                    <textarea name="comment_text"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini pull-right">Hozzászólok</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function action_loadstream()
    {

        $data['posts'] = Main::get_stream();
        $data['comments'] = Main::get_stream_comment();
        return View::forge('main/loadstream', $data);
    } 

    function action_post_stream()
    {

        Main::post_stream();
        $data['get'] = Main::get_stream();
        $stream = json_encode(
            array(
                'full_name' => $data['get'][0]['full_name'],
                'stream_text' => Input::auto_link(Input::nl2br_limit($data['get'][0]['stream_text'], 2)),
                'stream_id' => $data['get'][0]['stream_id'],
                )
            );
        return $stream;
    }
```

jQuery

```
//stream load
        $('#stream-load').load(site_url + "main/loadstream", function(){
            //oembed();
            $('.stream-comment textarea').elastic();
    }); 

//stream comment send
            $('.stream-comment-form').on('submit', function(){
                var commentData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: site_url + "main/post_stream_comment",
                    data: commentData,
                    success: function()
                    {
                        alert('yay');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

        }, 100000).hide().fadeIn("slow");


    function embedHtml(stream)
    {
        var html = '';
            html += '<div class="span6 stream-content">';
            html += '<p class="stream-user"><a href="#">'+stream.full_name+'</a></p>';
            html += '<p>'+stream.stream_text+'</p>';
            html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
            html += '<div class="feedback">';
            html += '<a href="">Tetszik</a> - ';
            html += '<a href="#" class="comment">Hozzászólás</a>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
        return html;
    }

    //stream post send
    $('#stream-form').on('submit', function(){
        var streamData = $(this).serialize();
        $('#stream-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: site_url + "main/post_stream",
            data: streamData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(stream)
            {

                $('#stream-submit').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#stream textarea').val('');
                $('#stream-load').prepend(embedHtml(stream));
                $('.stream-posts:first-child').hide().slideDown("slow");
                //oembed();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

First, I don't want anybody to write this for me, I just would like to ask a more experienced developer to look through my code and give me some hints about returning the comments logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the stream posts array, you can pluck the id's from that, then do one query to the db, to fetch all the related comments. Loop through that, and attach it to the post object/array. It's similar to an ORM eager loading pattern. So:

```
// get all the post ids
$post_ids = Arr::pluck($result, 'id'); // since 1.3

// fetch all relating comments in one query
$comments = DB::select()
    ->from('stream_comments')
    ->where('post_id', 'in', $post_ids)
    ->execute()
    ->as_array();

// attach them to the original result set.
foreach($comments as $comment)
{
    is_array($result[$comments['post_id']]) or $result[$comments['post_id']] = array();

    $result[$comments['post_id']][] = $comment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ORM to make a relationship between the post and gather it's related comments. That's what I would do.